# Bootstrap AngularJS Pagination with a Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, multidimensional-array, pagination

I am having trouble creating a pagination within a pagination, or multidimensional array pagination.
It is not showing the second page of the sub-pagination.

I could be wrong, but this seems like unexpected behavior. 
A bug in Bootstrap, or is it something else?

Here is a Plunker that I forked from a Bootstrap example. http://plnkr.co/edit/4kph6VXHWKekd5ef3kdS?p=preview

The JavaScript

```
   angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PaginationDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {

    // Initializing Array A & B Example
    $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.smallItemsPerPage = 2;

      $scope.bigCurrentPage = $scope.smallCurrentPage = 1;

 $scope.maxSize = 5;

    $scope.aArray = [{bArray : [{a:'a'},{b:'b'},{c:'c'}]},
                    {bArray : [{a:'d'},{b:'g'},{c:'f'}]},
                    {bArray : [{a:'w'},{b:'z'},{c:'e'}]}
      ]

// End A & B


    }) .filter('offset', function () {
            return function (input, start) {
                if (input === undefined || !angular.isArray(input)) {
                    return null;
                }
                start = +start; //parse to int
                return input.slice(start);
            };
        });
```

The HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Default</h4>
    <b>Page {{bigCurrentPage}} of Array A</b>
           <pagination total-items="aArray.length" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-lg" boundary-links="true"></pagination>

<div ng-repeat="aObject in aArray | offset: itemsPerPage * (bigCurrentPage-1) | limitTo: itemsPerPage">


    <pagination total-items="aObject.bArray.length" items-per-page="smallItemsPerPage" ng-model="smallCurrentPage" class="pagination-sm" maxsize="smallMaxSize" boundary-links="true"></pagination>
    <b>Page {{smallCurrentPage}} of Array B{{($index + 1) + ( (bigCurrentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage)}}</b>
<p ng-repeat="bObject in aObject.bArray | orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo:smallItemsPerPage | offset: smallItemsPerPage * (testresults.smallCurrentPage-1)">
    {{bObject}}                        
</p>
</div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```